# Переход по ссылке при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть страничка на сайте, есть каталог подбора автозапчастей. ЦМС предусмотрена замена урлов, однако т.к. ссылка имеет [такой вид](https://partseasy.ru/il_catalogs/chevrolet?il_catalog_params%5Bbrand%5D=chevrolet&il_catalog_params%5Bfunction%5D=getParts&il_catalog_params%5Bgroup%5D=1&il_catalog_params%5Bimage%5D=RT1311&il_catalog_params%5Bmarket%5D=GEN&il_catalog_params%5Bmodel%5D=T02&il_catalog_params%5Bmodelcode%5D=T&il_catalog_params%5Bpartgroup%5D=13110&il_catalog_params%5Bsubgroup%5D=3&il_catalog_params%5Bvin%5D=&il_catalog_params%5Byear%5D=2008)
такой адрес не удается вставить в "замену". Что хочу сделать - разместить на странице код и допустим эту ссылку, чтобы при прогрузке страницы выполнялось действие - переход по ссылке. [страничка](https://partseasy.ru/spravochnaya-informatsiya/1234.html)

Comment: ничо не понял. что надо-то?

Comment: при клике - закинуть нужный урл в куки/localstorage, а на странице поиска - вытащить данные, и закинуть в поиск

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то вам нужно

```
<?
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```